# fastest access to some member of 500 000 collection

Tags: c#, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [construct orderbook from orders example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930507/construct-orderbook-from-orders-example)

I would like to rephrase my previous question [construct orderbook from orders example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930507/construct-orderbook-from-orders-example) because it very bad phrased please don't read it :)

I receive orders updates, each **new** order has +1 orderId:

```
new orderid = 1 price = 100 quantity = 10
new orderid = 2 price = 101 quantity = 10
modify orderid = 1 price = 100 quantity = 8
new orderid = 3 price = 100 quantity = 7
new orderid = 4 price = 101 quantity = 3
delete orderid = 1
and so on
```

On each order update I need to calculate orderbook, after `delete orderid = 1` it would be:

```
price = 100 totalQuantity = 7
price = 101 totalQuantity = 13
```

Let's assume that initially both `orders` and `orderbook` are empty

I think I should write something like that:

```
if (order.action = add)
    orderBook[order.price] += order.quantity
if (order.action = delete)
    orderBook[order.price] -= getLastQuantity(order.id)
if (order.action = modify)
    orderBook[order.price] += order.quantity - getLastQuantity(order.id)
```

Probably you can suggest different implementation but this one is the most trivial I think
The problem is: how to implement `getLastQuantity(int orderId)`

Trivial implementation:

```
int[] lastQuantity = new int[100000000];

public int getLastQuantity(int orderId) {
    return lastQuantity[orderId];
}
```

occupies too much memory and I'm even not sure how fast is it

another trivial implementation is to use `Dictionary`, but I have **ordered int keys that go one by one** how can I use this fact to improve perfomance?

Note once order is deleted I don't need to remember "lastQuantity" of it. I only need "lastQuantity" of active orders.

- total number of orders is not more than 100 000 000
- active orders is less then 500 000

Comment: @DBM it would be even slower than using `Dictionary` to store 500 000 of active orders by orderId

Comment: Don't repost, edit and improve your questions. People already took the time and trouble to answer you.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an SortedDictionary. Here is a good article on performance for dictionary vs hash vs sortedlist vs sorted dictionary collections: http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Essentially, inserts are expensive but retrievals are not.

From MSDN:

> The SortedDictionary generic class is a binary search
>   tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the
>   dictionary. In this respect, it is similar to the SortedList generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and
>   both have O(log n) retrieval. Where the two classes differ is in
>   memory use and speed of insertion and removal:
>
> SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.
>
> SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList.
>
> If the list is populated all at once from sorted data,
>   SortedList is faster than SortedDictionary.
>
> The SortedDictionary generic class is a binary search
>   tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the
>   dictionary. In this respect, it is similar to the SortedList generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and
>   both have O(log n) retrieval. Where the two classes differ is in
>   memory use and speed of insertion and removal:
>
> SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.
>
> SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList.
>
> If the list is populated all at once from sorted data,
>   SortedList is faster than SortedDictionary.

Comment: I have about 48% insert, 48% delete and 2% retreive. (but to delete order it also need to be found)

Comment: I don't have any data on removals. In the blog he has the source code he used for the test. Feel free to edit that and include deletes to check performance speed. Off hand, I assume deletes will be speedy since it is essentially: find index, remove, all remaining indexes move down one.

Comment: See update to original answer

Comment: i've marked as correct answer however I need to investigate which particular collection better feet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a List, rather than an array, due to the fact that there is not a determinate size.  It will grow on its own as needed, without being overly large from the start or creating too many new arrays.

A Dictionary wouldn't be all that bad.  It would potentially have a little bit more wasted space than a List, and will perform marginally slower due to collisions, but it wouldn't be a bad solution.  A Dictionary would also perform better with the 'delete' operation, so if you do a lot of deleting I would go with a dictionary.

Comment: yes I do a lot of deleting because I have 500 000 (maximum) of active orders and other 99 500 000 are deleted. Also I need to do "search" fast, so I should use tree, not list.

Comment: actually I insert in 49% of cases, delete in 49% of cases and retrieve in 2% of cases

Comment: I'd go with a Dictionary over a sorted dictionary.  Adding/searching/removing/modifying a value based on a key is extremely fast with a dictionary, and that's exactly what you're doing here.